# How to get the defining class from a method body?

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, methods

I have two classes:

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        print(<get the defining class>)

class B(A):
    pass
```

Now, I need to replace `<get the defining class>` by a code such that this:

```
a = A()
b = B()
a.foo()
b.foo()
```

produces this (i.e. this is the expected behaviour):

```
A
A
```

I tried `self.__class__.__name__` but that obviously produces `B` for the last call as the `self` is, in fact, of class `B`.

So the ultimate question is: if I'm in a method body (which is not a class method), how can I get the name of the class the method is defined in?

Comment: I'm confused. If A & A is wrong and A & B isn't what you expect - what actually do you expect?

Comment: @JonClements No, A & A is correct. I'll rephrase the question, thanks for pointing the confusion out.

Comment: Right... if we were to do `class C: def foo(self) # whatever` - then a `class D(B, C)` where is `foo` "defined" then?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this is by using the functions qualified name:

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        print(self.foo.__qualname__[0])

class B(A):
    pass
```

The qualified name consists of the class defined and the function name in `cls_name.func_name` form. `__qualname__[0]` suits you here because the class name consists of a single character; it's better of course to split on the dot and return the first element  `self.foo.__qualname__.split('.')[0]`.

For both, the result is:

```
>>> a = A()
>>> b = B()
>>> a.foo()
A
>>> b.foo()
A
```

A more robust approach is climbing the `__mro__` and looking inside the `__dict__`s of every class for a function `type(self).foo`:

```
def foo(self):
    c = [cls.__name__ for cls in type(self).__mro__ if getattr(type(self), 'foo', None) in cls.__dict__.values()]
    print(c[0])
```

This is a bit more complex but yields the same result.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming that you don't want to hard-code this logic into each function, since you could do so trivially in your example code.

If the `print` statement is always the first statement of the methods for which you want this behaviour, one possible solution would be to use a decorator.

```
def print_defining_class(fn):
    calling_class = fn.__qualname__.split('.')[0]
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        print(calling_class)
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated

class A:
    @print_defining_class
    def method(self): pass

class B(A): pass

A().method() # A
B().method() # A
```